# How to check if member method is called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a class(Let's say: ***Parent***) that **creates** inside ***Member*** object.

I wonder, how I can test that **member** method is called on **parent** method call.

Let's see an example:

```
class Parent : public IParent
{
public:
    Member() : member{} {}
    void parent_method() override
    {
        member.member_method();
    }
private:
    Member member;
}
```

I would like to prepare test that would check if ***member_method*** is called on ***parent_method*** call using **GTest / GMock.**

**Important**: I would like to avoid polymorphic calls or any dynamic allocations - if it possible.

I had idea to pass some Factory in constructor and build proper Member object (real or mock) but it needs polymorphic calls and dynamic allocations.
I want to avoid this overhead.

Is there any method to do it in quite clean way?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to solve this unless you can mock the `Member` object itself. And that requires polymorphism or a factory pattern. Unless you can wrap it in an `#ifdef` instead.

Comment: When I needed to prove to myself (and my team lead) that my device driver 'touched-the-hw" (a hw-with-attitude that sometimes ignored my code),  I used a counting-log (a few nano-seconds to address and increment a counter).  The called method incremented a counter at exit, sometimes entrance, other times both.  The ram based log had an easily accessed show and clear debug ui.   Operationally, the test team commanded something that caused a hw change, then inspected / dumped the count log.

Comment: A slightly more intrusive approach (compared to the previous) was to have the method put an integer into an array used in round-robin mode.  I used the sign to indicate direction (read or write).  And the sequence indicated the 'order'ing of driver activities dealing with the stubborn hw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to do it with templates. The following is a variation of what is recommended in the google mock's documentation, [mock non-virtual methods using templates](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace std;

// YOUR SUT
class IParent
{
public:
    virtual ~IParent() {};

    virtual void parent_method() = 0;
};

class Member
{
public:
    void member_method()
    {
        cout << "member_method\n";
    }
};

template <class T = Member>   // make it a template
class Parent : public IParent
{
public:
    Parent() : member{} {}
    void parent_method() override
    {
        member.member_method();
    }
private:
    using member_type = T;
    member_type member; // member is now of type T (i.e. member_type)

    template <class U>
    friend U& GetMemberForTestMock(Parent<U>& parent); // necessary to set
                                                       // mock expectations
                                                       // for private member
};


// code in the test/mock file as this function is only for
// testing with mockMembers
template <class U>
U& GetMemberForTestMock(Parent<U>& parent)
{
    return parent.member;
}

// Your mock class
class MockMember
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(member_method, void());
};


// Google Test
TEST(ParentTest, callsMemberMethodOnce)
{
    auto parent = Parent<MockMember>{};
    EXPECT_CALL(GetMemberForTestMock(parent), member_method()).Times(1);
    parent.parent_method();
}
```

You could eliminate the `friend` statement all together by modifying `Parent::Parent()` so that you can pass a pointer to Member or MockMember:

```
template <class T = Member>   // make it a template
class Parent : public IParent
{
public:
    using member_type = T;

    Parent(member_type* m) : member{m} {}
    void parent_method() override
    {
        member->member_method();
    }
private:
    member_type* member; // member is now of type T (i.e. member_type)
};
```

Then you can test like this:

```
TEST(ParentTest, callsMemberMethodOnceAgain)
{
    auto member = MockMember{};
    EXPECT_CALL(member, member_method()).Times(1);

    auto parent = Parent<MockMember>{&member};
    parent.parent_method();
}
```

Modifying `Parent`'s interface to provide a way to specify which `Member` to pass (or to "inject" a test Mock) is probably a good idea since it increases modularity (i.e. decreases the dependency between the two objects). It enables you to provide `Parent` with different `Member`s providing different functionality. This brings me to your concern about having several template parameters if you have more class members.

You shouldn't need to mock all members, not even "many" members. Most "good" size classes with one responsibility have few dependencies. You normally only have to mock other classes that have orthogonal responsibilities and that your class depends on. A good design tries to minimize these dependencies. If you find that you have many classes which have many dependencies on other classes, it may be a sign that your design can be improved.

That leaves us with performance since providing this modularity through polymorphism/inheritance comes at a cost due to the extra level of indirection. This is not the case, with templates since the type is selected at compile type. However, you may not want to make all of the classes with dependencies templates, so you have to reach a balance. It is difficult to "guess" what is going to significantly affect the performance of the overall system and by how much. In fact, there is no reliable way other than measuring. Therefore, I suggest that you take your best guess but concentrate on a good design and on your code being readable and working correctly. Then, after measuring, if there are performance problems, fix them. A lot depends on your domain, but in my experience, this kind of indirection is rarely the cause of performance problems.

NOTE: I tested the code presented using gcc version 7.2.0 (with the C++17 flag) and googletest 1.8.0.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about such solution. Although when having many members and making all o them templated may not be a good idea. Declaring all tests as friends is not elegant too. I consider changing it to virtual calls to test it properly, but I am afraid of substantial decrease of perfomance.

Comment: Yes, declaring all tests as friends is not good. It would be different if it was just one test class. I think this solution may be improved though. I'll try to address your concerns when I get a chance (it will be a busy day).

Comment: I edited it to address the "all tests as friends" issue with a GetMember external function. More later...